Predictive back gets stuck if an edit text has focus during the back gesture
I'm currently trying to implement predictive back in my app and I ran into a bug.
This appears to be an Android 14 or Samsung OS bug. The conditions of the bug appears to be:

predictive back is enabled
user is on a dialog fragment screen with an edit text
the edit text has focus and it is in the "select text" mode (the cursor is in the shape of a teardrop instead of a vertical line)

If the user slowly initiates the back gesture predictive back is triggered but then it gets stuck. No cancel event is fired (handleOnBackCancelled() is not called).
I was able to reproduce this bug on a S24 with the latest updates (Android 14) however I could not reproduce the bug on a Pixel 7 with the latest updates (also Android 14). I know that the pixel line got 2 specific OS patches so it might just be that the Pixel 7 has gotten a fix where as the Samsung OS did not pull in the fix. However I did not rule out the possibility that this is a Samsung specific bug.
If anyone knows why or a workaround let me know.

I was able to find out a bit more about the bug.
I was able to reproduce the same exact behavior/bug in the Gmail app by opening an email, tapping on the reply box, then typing some text to trigger the "select text" mode. Then if I issue a back gesture near the bottom of the screen (the gesture needs to be down near the bottom or else the reply will close) I can reproduce the bug on a S24 device. This means that the bug is likely not unique to my app.

This bug seems to be an Android 14 bug OR a Samsung OS bug. I do not have a non-Pixel and non-Samsung Android 14 device to confirm.
I was able to think of a workaround since it's unlikely there is a solution to the bug outside of just updating the OS.
The workaround is to remove the state where the EditText has focus yet the keyboard is not shown. As far as I can tell eliminating this state does not reduce the user experience.
The way I did this was by setting up a listener for the keyboard visibility like so:
class MyDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {
  ...
  private val isKeyboardHiddenState = MutableStateFlow(true)

  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(binding.root) { v, windowInsets ->
      val imeInset = windowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime())
      isKeyboardHiddenState.value = imeInset.bottom == 0
      WindowInsetsCompat.CONSUMED
    }

    viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
      isKeyboardHiddenState.collect { isKeyboardHidden ->
        if (isKeyboardHidden && myEditText.isFocused) {
          myEditText.clearFocus()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

